# convert laravel 9 custom Rule to laravel 10 Rule

Tags: php, laravel, rules

i have a custom Rule in laravel 9 and it has passes and message function like this:

```
<?php

namespace Auth\Http\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CustomRule implements Rule
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (strlen($value) == 15) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'value is invalid';
    }
}
```

but in laravel 10 when you create custom Rule , there is just validate function like this:

```
public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
```

so can i use old rule without any change or must change?! how to change?!

Comment: Instead of a custom rule, you can just use "size:15" for this.

Otherwise just use the command to generate a new rule, and copy paste the body of `passes()` to `validate()`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#using-rule-objects

Comment: the rule size 15 is just a sample, my custom rule is complex a little bit!

Comment: Check docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#using-rule-objects. rename passes to validate and instead of return false use $fail('value is invalid') and dont return true

Comment: Obviously, if you need a `validate()` method, and you don't have one, you can't use the old rule without any changes. The documentation is quite clear about how to write the method.